# Why will function1( ) raise "NameError" when analogous function2( ) won't?

Tags: python, function, lambda, global-variables, nameerror

I defined the following functions:

```
import math
from numpy import nan
from datetime import date
mismatch_day = date(2022, 12, 1)

def get_pre_end(row, mism_day):
    global end_pre
    if row['date'] < mism_day:
        end_pre = row['date_end']
    return end_pre

def get_post_end(row, mism_day):
    global end_post
    if row['date'] >= mism_day:
        end_post = row['date_end']
    return end_post
```

When I run `get_pre_end()`, I get the expected output (a list):

```
post_end_df = pd.DataFrame()
post_end_df['post_end'] = bydate_df.apply(lambda row: get_post_end(row, mismatch_day), axis=1)
post_end_list = post_end_df['post_end'].tolist()
post_end_list = [item for item in post_end_list if not(math.isnan(item)) == True]
```

Output:

`[228.7, 179.3, 168.7, 111.9, 189.2, 220.6, 165.7, 183.8, 215.6,` ...

However, when I run `get_post_end()`, python raises a 'NameError':

```
post_end_df = pd.DataFrame()
post_end_df['post_end'] = bydate_df.apply(lambda row: get_post_end(row, mismatch_day), axis=1)
post_end_list = post_end_df['post_end'].tolist()
post_end_list = [item for item in post_end_list if not(math.isnan(item)) == True]
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[32], line 2
      1 post_end_df = pd.DataFrame()
----> 2 post_end_df['post_end'] = bydate_df.apply(lambda row: get_post_end(row, mismatch_day), axis=1)
      3 post_end_list = post_end_df['post_end'].tolist()
      4 post_end_list = [item for item in post_end_list if not(math.isnan(item)) == True]

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:8839, in DataFrame.apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwargs)
   8828 from pandas.core.apply import frame_apply
   8830 op = frame_apply(
   8831     self,
   8832     func=func,
   (...)
   8837     kwargs=kwargs,
   8838 )
-> 8839 return op.apply().__finalize__(self, method="apply")

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:727, in FrameApply.apply(self)
    724 elif self.raw:
    725     return self.apply_raw()
--> 727 return self.apply_standard()

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:851, in FrameApply.apply_standard(self)
    850 def apply_standard(self):
--> 851     results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    853     # wrap results
    854     return self.wrap_results(results, res_index)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:867, in FrameApply.apply_series_generator(self)
    864 with option_context("mode.chained_assignment", None):
    865     for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    866         # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 867         results[i] = self.f(v)
    868         if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    869             # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because
    870             #  series_generator will swap out the underlying data
    871             results[i] = results[i].copy(deep=False)

Cell In[32], line 2, in <lambda>(row)
      1 post_end_df = pd.DataFrame()
----> 2 post_end_df['post_end'] = bydate_df.apply(lambda row: get_post_end(row, mismatch_day), axis=1)
      3 post_end_list = post_end_df['post_end'].tolist()
      4 post_end_list = [item for item in post_end_list if not(math.isnan(item)) == True]

Cell In[20], line 5, in get_post_end(row, mism_day)
      3 if row['date'] >= mism_day:
      4     end_post = row['date_end']
----> 5 return end_post

NameError: name 'end_post' is not defined
```

I cannot understand why `get_post_end()` raises this 'NameError', when var `end_post` is globally defined and the `else` statement handles rows that do not fulfill the `if` statement. Can anyone explain why I am getting 'NameError' and how can I fix that?

Comment: What if the `if` condition isn't fulfilled? Then the variable you're trying to `return` isn't being defined.

Comment: I know that the `if` conditional should be fulfilled because there are elements that attend the if-condition.

Comment: Well, apparently it's *not* being fulfilled. But regardless of what exactly happens in your specific case: your code is unsafe because it will produce exactly this error **if the condition is unfulfilled and the variable is never declared.** What do you *want* to happen in this case?

Comment: Note that the `if` conditional has to be fulfilled by the **first** row that the function is called with in order to avoid an error here. In fact, if you apply `get_post_end` and `get_pre_end` to the same Series, then one of them is guaranteed to fail, because their `if` statements can't both be true for the first entry in the series.

Comment: @deceze, `date_end` is a series of values that happen in a daily basis. Because `mismatch_day` is a date within this time-frame, there will always be rows that attend `if row['date'] >= mism_day`, whether or not the code is safe. Now, if the first row is decisive to determine which function will fail, as observed by @slothrop, then this first row is the cause of this 'NameError' issue.

Comment: @NigelBlainey but the relevant question isn't "does some row, anywhere in the series, satisfy the conditional?". It's "does the first row satisfy the conditional?". You can see in the part of the stack trace headed `~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:867` that the apply operation works by calling the function sequentially on each row in turn.

Comment: Sorry: you've beent teled why this error raises. Programming is a deterministic thing, and although when things get more complex, erros may be harder to stop, that is not the case here. You asked a question, and people with several years of experience are telling you what is the cause: your variable is not initialized in the cases the error raises, and that is because it is conditionally declared. So, the condition is false when the error raises. That is your answer.

Comment: I've added an `else` statement to the functions as suggested (see edited question), and assigned `float('NaN')` for the rows that do not fulfill the if statement. I think the solution is safe now.

Answer (score 1):

The `global` statement does not define a variable. When the if statement in get_post_end is not fulfilled, the variable `end_post` will not be assigned but tried to be returned. -> error.

Answer (score 0):

I've included `else` statements to the functions and dropped `float('NaN')` from the lists using `math.isnan()`. As a result, the functions are now able to handle the issues caused by the first rows. Here is the full code:

```
import math
from numpy import nan
from datetime import date
mismatch_day = date(2022, 12, 1)

def get_pre_end(row, mism_day):
    global end_pre
    if row['date'] < mism_day:
        end_pre = row['date_end']
    else:
        end_pre = float('NaN')
    return end_pre

def get_post_end(row, mism_day):
    global end_post
    if row['date'] >= mism_day:
        end_post = row['date_end']
    else:
        end_post = float('NaN')
    return end_post

pre_end_df = pd.DataFrame()
pre_end_df['pre_end'] = bydate_df.apply(lambda row: get_pre_end(row, mismatch_day), axis=1)
pre_end_list = pre_end_df['pre_end'].tolist()
pre_end_list = [item for item in pre_end_list if not(math.isnan(item)) == True]
post_end_df = pd.DataFrame()
post_end_df['post_end'] = bydate_df.apply(lambda row: get_post_end(row, mismatch_day), axis=1)
post_end_list = post_end_df['post_end'].tolist()
post_end_list = [item for item in post_end_list if not(math.isnan(item)) == True]
```

Comment: Since you're using global variables anyway, you could just define those variables globally with `float('NaN')` as default value, instead of doing it with an `else`.